# Able to mount but not able to view the contents of LUKS-encrypted flash drives

Tags: partitioning, mount, nautilus, encryption, luks

I've formatted multiple flash drives on multiple computers using the Gnome Disk Utility on Ubuntu 16.04, each with a Ext4/LUKS partition. All is fine on the machine used to format them, but I'm unable to view the contents on other machines. I get a "The location could not be displayed. You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of $DRIVE_NAME" message from Nautilus immediately after successful mounting.

Comment: Ubuntu version?

Comment: All machines are 16.04

Comment: Have you installed "cryptsetup" on the affected machines? It is needed for decrypting LUKS, but last time that I checked, isn't installed by default (unless you encrypted your home directory or installed to LUKS during system installation).

Comment: That's not the issue. All machines have cryptsetup as they use LUKS for full-disk encryption. Also, they mount fine when I enter the correct passphrase. I just can't view the contents.

Comment: Just formatted a flash drive with an Ext4/LUKS partition using Tails. Contents of the drive are viewable on both Ubuntu 16.04 and Fedora 24.

Seems as though this is an issue that only occurs if you create a LUKS partition with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

When using Gnome Disk Utility on recent versions of Ubuntu to create an encrypted LUKS+ext4 partition, the resulting partition will have the following permissions set by default:

- Owner Access: Create and delete files
- Group Access: none
- Others Access: none

If you want to access this partition on other machines, in most cases, you’ll have to change permissions as appropriate. For example, **while other permissions settings may be more appropriate for some use cases**, you could change the permissions to be as follows:

- Owner Access: Create and delete files
- Group Access: Create and delete files
- Others Access: Create and delete files

Here’s how to change the permissions:

- After using Gnome Disk Utility on recent versions of Ubuntu to create the encrypted partition, eject the USB.
- Reinsert the USB on the machine on which it was created (and if requested, enter the appropriate password).
- Open Nautilus and find the USB listed in the left pane.
- Right click on the icon associated with the USB.
- Click on “Properties” in the resulting dialog.
- Go to the “Permissions” tab, and set the permissions as suggested above **or as appropriate**.

The above could also be accomplished using the command line. But I'll leave to others to provide instructions for doing so.